# como se utiliza la aplicación de launch4j 3.50

Tags: launch4j

Estoy tratando de crear el ejecutable de mi aplicación (.exe) mediante launch4j versión 3.50

Ya cree mi aplicación java con maven mediante el ide netbeans y obtuve el .jar, estuve viendo varios videos donde usan el launch4j (con versiones anteriores entre ellas la más usada la 3.12) para crear el .exe solo que tengo una confusión en la pestaña del JRE ya que algunos crean una carpeta JRE en el directorio del proyecto y copian el contenido del JDK y otros simplemente apuntan a la carpeta del JRE que se encuentra en C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

**Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con este tema ya que no he podido encontrar documentación que me sea útil**